# Biography of Rabbi Yisrael Yitzchak (Yishai) Chassidah

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, yahrtzeit

Author of the Jewish Encyclopedia of Biblical Personalities - Ishei Tanakh.

I am having great difficulty finding any information on the Rav. Is he alive? Does he have other works? Any shiurim/books on his life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a little info on [this site](http://www.bet-fisher.co.il/history/people/founderpage/?id=17682). I'll translate it into English:

Rabbi Chassidah was born in Warsaw in 1910. When he was 14, he and his family made aliyah and settled in Haifa. Eventually he received semicha for being a Shochet U'Vodek, and then began to look for a job in the Galilee. Thanks to connections he had with [Rabbi Binyamin Mendelsohn](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9F), the rabbi of K'far Ata (today [Kiryat Ata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiryat_Ata)), he became the ShU"v of K'far Ata. At one point he also learned Milah and also worked as a mohel. When the State of Israel was founded, he moved to Yerushalayim.

According to [this site](https://data.bnf.fr/fr/13526614/israel_isaac_chasidah/) and [Hebrewbooks](https://hebrewbooks.org/41580), he passed away in 2003.

Some other books he wrote (according to the list in the National Library of Israel (NLI), he wrote many, so I won't bring all of them):

- Otzar Ma'amarei Halacha - pt. [1](https://hebrewbooks.org/41580) and [2](https://hebrewbooks.org/41581) available on Hebrewbooks
- Zicharon Levnei Yisrael: Autobiographia, kollel toldot HaYeshuv Kiryat Ata, Masa'ot U'chvayot ([NLI](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001049723/NLI))
- Biurei Hachassidut LaShas ([NLI](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001919778/NLI))
- Rabbi Chaim Falagi U's'farav ([NLI](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001006671/NLI))
- Edited an anonymous kuntress on Chanukah ([NLI](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH003876163/NLI))
- Tehillot Yisrael (an edition of Sefer Tehillim) ([NLI](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001258795/NLI))
- Karmei Yisrael - Biurim VeChiddushim Betanach, BeMa'amarei Chazal U'veseder Hatefillah ([NLI](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001135324/NLI))
- Piyut Ha'deah Vehaneshama ([NLI](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001805367/NLI))
- Biurei Hachassidut La'Nach ([NLI](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH002176806/NLI))

He also wrote some essays.